# Why does a float always end as .0000.. after dividing?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  int a;float b;
  scanf("%d",&a);
  b=a/4;
  printf("%f",b);
}
```

For example, 9 divided by 4 should print 2.25 but instead it prints 2.0000. Why?

Comment: Integer division. `b=a/4.0;`

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` is an `int`. You should cast `a` to a `float`, like this

```
b = (float)a /4;
```

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an integer, so your division is performed with integers throughout then the result is coerced to a float when you assign it to `b`